# How do you configure jshint or eslint differently per environment in ember-cli?

Tags: ember-cli

I want to support the usage of 'debugger' statements locally and on the development deployment but not when it gets to staging or production.

I'm using Ember-cli with environments and am not understanding how to define the jshint or eslint directives differently.

Answer (score 0):

By design we can configure both linting libraries differently via their configuration files for app code & test code via `.eslintrc` or `.jshintrc` files which reside at the root folder and the tests folder. So even though  we can have different rules for these categories of code, we can't differentiate them per environment.

The reason it might not make sense to do so is because the assets that get generated after the build process that gets deployed doesn't necessarily need to conform to these rules since transpilers like babel (may) optimize generated code for us.

While I don't understand the need to keep `debugger` statements after a debugging session in the codebase, you can use [broccoli-strip-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-strip-debug) to remove them automatically in production builds and disable the debugger flag in the linting configuration altogether which gets you the setup you're looking for.